# Fast Html viewer QT

Tags: html, qt, optimization, widget, qwebengineview

I want to open html file in qt app. This html is very big. it has 13000 lines. I used the QWebEngineView, but the problem is that it flips through the page with delays. I need a widget to work quickly with large html files. What idea is there for this?

Comment: 6mb file need to open.

Comment: What do you mean by `"it flips through the page with delays"`?  From what I understand the `QWebEngine*` stuff is based on Google's Chromium engine so finding something faster might not be trivial.